# Calling Scalar functions in SQL Server 2012 database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, web-services, function

To give you a background, I am working on a C# web service project using Entity Framework. Our main web application will make calls to our web service and send us the data object that encompasses several fields.

One of the things they are sending us is the Social Security Number which is not encrypted and looks like this for example, 123456789.

Since we are using entity framework, we have to call a scalar function in the database that will pass in the SSN string, encrypt it (`varbinary(256)` as the data type), and send it back to the web service application.

However, it is not returning anything and I know that in C#, the equivalent to `varbinary(256)` is `byte[]`. I have even added the SQL function to our Entity Framework model.

This is the function we are using and the call we are making but not currently working. Any advice on this would be great

```
//Function call
[EdmFunction("ClinicalDoc.Store", "EncryptText")]
public static byte[] EncryptText(string SSN)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}

nCharge.SSN(where nCharge is the data object) = EncryptText(SSN);
```

Can someone look at this and see what I'm missing?

Comment: I have also had problems storing a C# byte array in SQL Server.